# Botometer keeps returning TypeError

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy, botdetect

I have used this function before and it worked perfectly. However, I may have accidentally changed something and it now returns the error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

For the line:

```
bom = botometer.botometer(wait_on_ratelimit=True,rapidapi_key=rapidapi_key,**twitter_app_auth)
```

The full code I use is:

```
def bot_detector(account,lang='universal'):
    consumer_secret = deleter(open('consumer_sxcrxt.txt','r').rxad(),'\n')
    consumer_key = deleter(open('api.txt','r').read(),'\n')
    twitter_app_auth = {'consumer_key': consumer_key,'consumer_secret': consumer_secret}
    rapidapi_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    bom = botometer.botometer(wait_on_ratelimit=True,rapidapi_key=rapidapi_key,**twitter_app_auth)
    result = bom.check_account(account)
    score = result['cap'][lang]
    return score

print(bot_detector(1.25948029617448E+018))
```

Notes:

- 'deleter' is just a way for me to remove the line separator on the files containing my api keys.
- I just checked and my twitter api keys are working.
- If I put botometer.Botometer as it says on the documentation, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'botometer' has no attribute 'Botometer'
```

(I think they made a typo on the documentation.)

Documentation:
https://libraries.io/pypi/botometer

Answer (score 2):

I named my file 'botometer.py' and thus python was looking in the wrong place.